# Древовидный список для веб страницы, как в wxp

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую всех вошедших

Представьте себе проводник windows xp (да, не 7ки, а xp). Там с лева была древовидная структура папок. На JQ UI такого нету. В интернете для web страниц - решения есть, но одно другого кривее. У кого то нет соединяющих линий от раскрытой папки к остальным, у кого то уровня всего 2, у кого то список на ul li, что затрагивает свои стили, а у кого то список не может быть изначально открыт на определенном значении (папки)

Может ли кто посоветовать решение? Может есть уже готовое, в интернете или самописное?

p.s. самое обидное такие решения год назад были в инете в огромных кол-вах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 сек. [гуглирования](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=jquery+dir+tree#q=jquery+dir+tree) и [вуаля](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/)

Comment: ох.. умел бы я гуглить по английски ) Спасибо огромное!